# Why can't I see some of my pictures in the gallery?

Tags: android, cursor, sd-card, mediastore

I'm trying to read photos existing in the sdcard with  MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA but I'm always getting an empty cursor !!! 
This is the code I'm using for the reading :

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };

Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver()
    .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
    new String[] { "%"+eventName.trim()+"%" }, null);

imagecursor.setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>(); 
Log.i("imagecursor.getCount()", Integer.toString(imagecursor.getCount()));

for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
}
```

Of course I added this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was with the Media Scanner so i solved it buy using a simple app called Scan Media witch scan the external storage and then the MediaStore will be able to find the new elements .

Answer (score -1):

i don´t know if this will help you but I is working me

```
String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getAbsolutePath();

String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/yoururl/";

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
for (File file : files){
    myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

in this example i get images and show in a grid view

Comment: He is searching the pictures into a database, not directly with a path.